# Do prisoners have to be extracted in one go for The Phantom Pain?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes, metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Ground Zeroes you can apparently use all extracted prisoners in The Phantom Pain. For example, in the titular mission, there are apparently 7 you can rescue: Paz, Chico, the four prisoners outside, and the one scheduled for execution.

Do these all need to be rescued in one go for use in The Phantom Pain, or can they be extracted in different attempts?

Comment: Voting to leave open as per [When is a game publicly available?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5541/4797)  "*If a "pre-release" question about a game can be asked and answered without speculation because an alpha/beta/early version exists, **regardless of the number of people who are/could be in possession of said game**, it should be left open.*"

Comment: http://www.gamespot.com/articles/hideo-kojima-spotted-in-metal-gear-solid-5/1100-6430223/ This article seems to indicate that you don't get them all right away - "Kaz... explains that several characters who were rescued in Ground Zeroes will eventually join Mother Base."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the GZ section, I have read that each 'special' prisoner/character/extractee is flagged individually, and that each one can be extracted in separate runs of the mission they appear in, so long as that mission run is played to completion, and Snake leaves Camp Omega safely.

For the TPP section, there is a screenshot floating around from a strategy guide that shows the special volunteers from GZ being introduced gradually over the course of the first few early episodes of TPP, rather than dropping all of them on you immediately after downloading your GZ save.